# cannot read property 'dispose' of null angular 4

Tags: angular

I am using matAutoComplete in angular 4.In this, I used to get data from the server.for that, I used the pipe here.

***ngFor="let c of characters | async**"

But pipe gives me an error like this.

"**cannot read property 'dispose' of null angular 4**".

please provide me a solution.Thank you!

Comment: check out this thread https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6243

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the type is not defined in component. Define it in the component. Like this

```
characters:any : Array<any> = [];
```

Then

```
<div *ngIf="characters.length > 0">
   <li *ngFor="let c of characters">
   
   </li>
</div> <!-- End -->
```